# Gravitational potential due to uniform ring

Tags: homework-and-exercises, gravity, newtonian-gravity, symmetry, potential

So i want to find the Gravitational potential caused by a uniform ring with radius $R$ at any point in space. I know the solution of the field should not have any dependence on the azimuthial angle due to symmetry, so the potential should be of this form:

$V=V(r,\theta)$

I know that you can solve this using Laplace's equation at the symmetric axis and then expand it for all of space and this indeed will give you a function that does not depend on $\phi$. I wanted to solve this using a different approach. Let's say the ring is made out of little masses $dm_i$ and everyone of those little masses creates a gravitational field. The position vector of each tiny mass is then: $\vec{r_i}=Rcos\phi_i i +Rsin\phi_ij$, according to this the potential that is created due to a tiny mass at any point with position vector $\vec{r}$ should be:

$dV=-G\frac{dm}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r_i}|}\Rightarrow V=-G\rho \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{d\phi_i}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r_i}|}\Rightarrow V=-G\rho \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{d\phi_i}{\sqrt{R^2-2rRsin\theta cos(\phi_i-\phi)+r^2}}$

My problem isn't that i cant solve the integral (which i can't) my problem is that whatever its solution at the end the potential, will have a dependence of $\phi$ which shouldn't be happenning. I can't understand what i am doing wrong, any tips will be apprecieated.

Comment: You can always say the azimuth is 0 by symmetry: you are free to start your polar coordinate system at the plane you are calculating the potential on.

Comment: Yes but how can this be shown methematically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the variable of integration to $\phi’_i=\phi_i-\phi$ and the dependence on $\phi$ will go away.

The new limits of integration will *look* different but you are still integrating over all 360 degrees of the ring so you can change them back to $0$ to $2\pi$.